# Magazines/Websites Similar To The New Yorker?

Tags: magazines

As everyone here probably knows, *The New Yorker* is held in high regard for their editorial process and excellent writing. I really appreciate their content, and I feel that they provide more than just an article — they provide a great literary experience. I often use them as inspiration for writing. *The New Yorker* also happens to be one of the few magazines I read (I only read the online version).

**But is there anything out there that compares to or exceeds the quality and content offered by *The New Yorker***?

I don't even know where to begin to look, but all suggestions are apprecaited!

(Tiny FYI: I'm not as interested in politics/entertainment stuff as I am just general news and technology-related content.)

Answer (score 4):

Some possibilities...

- [Harper's](http://www.harpers.org/)
- [The Atlantic](http://www.theatlantic.com/)
- [The Economist](http://www.economist.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I would also add:

- Entrepreneur
- Oxford American
- Esquire

These are sites I have personally found to be very similar to *The New Yorker* and that I myself read regularly, besides *The New Yorker*.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *adastone*! Your answer is pretty short and currently looks more like a comment. You can comment once you reach 50 reputation. Could you [edit] your answer to elaborate a bit on why this magazine has comparable or higher quality than *The New Yorker*? Are there studies out there that would support your claim for example? If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Well, @Secespitus, the problem here lies in the question. It asks for "magazines similar to *The New Yorker*", and apparently the three magazines that adastone named are similar. What else would (s)he write, when the questions asks for names of magazines? Your demand for studies is that support the claim that the magazines are similar is a bit ridiculous here.

Comment: I added that I myself found them similar because I constantly read them and therewith have the exact comparison..  the post just asked for similar magazines...

Comment: @Cloudchaser It asks for "anything out there that compares to or exceeds the quality and content offered by *The New Yorker*?" but the answer didn't mention any reason to believe the claim. To cite the post notice under the question: "We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed."

Comment: @Secespitus None of the other answers provide more than names of magazines. None of them give any kind of explanation or "studies". This answer is perfectly fine for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

For general Interest , you can refer to below magazines :

1) Clann Magazine.
2) The Believer
3) Harper's Magazine
4) Reader's Digest
5) The Saturday Evening Post

For technology content, you can refer to below magazines :

1) American Heritage of Invention & Technology
2) Invention & Technology
3) 2600: The Hacker Quarterly
4) Free Open Source Magazine
5) Modern Electrics
6) PCWorld
7) Wired

and many more.........

Answer (score 0):

For technology related content, you’d maybe like to read the [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14840)

Comment: @F1Krazy Did you read the question? The question asks for names of magazines similar to *The New Yorker*. The words "Smashing Magazine" are an exhaustive answer to that question. There really isn't anything more to say. – That downvote is unnecessary and mean.

Answer (score -2):

Try Aldaily (Arts And Letters Daily), Economist, Atlantic.